# What is a standard way to add a ViewController in a Mac OS X Cocoa app? (or is it required?)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'd like to start a Cocoa app with a `ViewController` just like the iOS "Single View App" template, but there is no such template (is there a public / open source one that can be used?)

Is it true that for Cocoa apps, we don't really need one, because an `NSView` can do everything already?  We can just put all the event handling in our custom NSView class.  Could it be that iOS requires it a lot more because rotation is handled by the ViewController and rotation is usually required?  But if we use MVC, then it might be better to always use a ViewController, and if so, is there a standard way, a template, to do it?

Answer (score 5):

The "Controller" in OS X with respect to managing NSViews is the `NSWindowController`. Though Drummer says that `NSViewController` isn't very useful, I must disagree - it is useful for splitting up your `NSWindowController` once it gets too large, and has clear logical divisions in terms of views.

You could have one `NSWindowController`, and once it gets complicated enough, the `NSWindowController` could delegate tasks corresponding to specific views to subclasses of `NSViewController`, and in that respect it is very useful.

In the default templates (if I remember correctly) the `AppDelegate` takes the role of the window controller, though it isn't technically one. In more complex applications it is a good idea to instantiate a window controller instead.

As long as you don't mix up the controller and view anything can be used. The View should be relegated to just display and basic input handling.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. Other than a popup, when you do actually need a NSViewController? Because for everything else in your NSWindow, you could simply use a custom view and give that custom view its own class. You don't have to have seperate NSViewControllers to split up and manage the contents in a NSWindow.

Answer (score 3):

On OS X `NSViewController` isn't as often used as `UIViewController` on iOS. One of the reasons is that it's not really useful and lacks a lot of the nice features of `UIViewController`. There are only a couple of situations where you really have to use them, like when using an [`NSPopover`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are several ways to structure your OS X code. One of them is using [`NSWindowController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can think of `NSWindowController` as the equivalent of `UIViewController` on iOS.

Comment: On OSX, you can't switch between NSViewControllers like you can on iOS right? So there is no sliding to the right and so on. So am I right in saying that it is pretty much only useful for popup views?

Comment: It's still useful for structuring your app, by separating independent parts of the app and implementing them in a view controller. For instance to implement something like the Mail app, you could have one view controller displaying the list of mails, and a second independent view controller that displays a selected email.