# developing multiple panels in a single view

Tags: cocoa

I'm new to cocoa development, and been trying to look for something similar in the attached image.

Basically an app with multiple views or sections or panels, where I'd link separate classes to each of them instead of one Delegate class doing everything.

I'm also confused between the old xib and the new storyboard style and wondering how can I accomplish the same, like what kind of visual objects to use. attached images explains where I'm trying to get at.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Mac OS Cocoa it's common to just uses plain `NSView` objects to hierarchically subdivide complex views.

If you also want visual dividers there's `NSBox`. For resizable parts use `NSSplitView`.

Regarding the controller tier it's also pretty common to set up individual controller objects for separated panes (subviews) in a window.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about one single view. So what is possible would be to create a background view and then add multiple custom subviews (`NSView` subclass), each with their own custom class to control them, and even custom controllers.

As to accomplish something that looks similar to the screenshot, you can select a few UI elements in interface builder and do Embed In > Box to group them like in the screenshot.

Comment: I see, so we have Boxes as panels or different sections of an app in cocoa, would I subclass `NSBox` to control each of those boxes, please also explain more, what is it when you say "custom controllers"

Comment: NSBox is a subclass of NSView, so yes you could subclass NSBox to control each part of your program. For the controllers, you can refer to that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448859/what-is-a-standard-way-to-add-a-viewcontroller-in-a-mac-os-x-cocoa-app-or-is-i

Comment: ok, I understand when you said custom class (linked to the box) but I didn't get you on custom controllers, isn't the same thing?

Comment: A ViewController as its name suggests, controls one or move view. Please read the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html

Comment: I see, so it's NSViewController (learned similar thing in iOS), now can you drag and drop multiple viewControllers on a window pane in interface builder as different sections of an app?

Comment: Try it, test it, try it again and if it doesn't work open up a new question on SO.